# WCF - Is it possible to listen to listen to a WCF ChannelFactory with a HttpListener or socket

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, websocket, communication

I'm implementing a little communication library for fun and it work pretty weel like wcf. All implementation was base on webRequest and HttpListener.

I'm asking if there is a way to listen or communicate with wcf and with which transportation layer I could do it.... I'm not asking if it's difficult to do or long. Just asking if someone knows how to do it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF utilizes different [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733027.aspx) that determine the protocol utilized to exchange messages between the client and the server. The difficulty of communicating with the service using a non-WCF mechanism such as WebRequest depends on the binding you've selected for your service.

Most of the WCF bindings utilize variations of the SOAP standard to exchange messages over various transports (HTTP, TCP, etc.), and it is pretty difficult to implement these correctly and completely. The simplest SOAP-based binding in WCF is the [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx), which is an implementation of the entire [WS-I Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1-2004-08-24.html) standard for interoperable web services.

However, there is one binding, [WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx), that uses [REST](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html)-style HTTP requests as opposed to SOAP for all its communication. REST services are pretty easy to understand, you basically just pass the method parameters as GET or POST parameters in your HTTP request. Trying to interoperate with that binding would probably be your best bet.